# Convert Heira variable to comma separated token

Tags: puppet

I have a yaml file where I can specify n number of options:

```
---
solr:
    - dev
    - test
```

I then call them into a puppet variable using heira:

```
if $solr_values == undef {
  $solr_values = hiera('solr', false)
}

if count($solr_values) > 0 {
  class { solr:
    cores => [ $solr_values ],
  }
}
```

However $solr_values is coming through as 'devtest' and not 'dev'. 'test' as I'd expect given that it's a list in yaml. Can someone advise on the best approach here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `[ $solr_values ]` gives you an array of arrays, e.g. `[ [ 'dev', 'test', ... ] ]`, which is likely not what you want.

I suggest plain

```
cores => $solr_values,
```

Note that when you use the array variable `$core`/`$solr_values` in a string, e.g.

```
$debug = "VALUES: '$solr_values'"
```

Puppet will coerce the array into a string by simply concatenating the values, so you will still end up with `'devtest...'`

What you want to do is make use of the [join](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-stdlib#join) function from the [stdlib](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/stdlib) module, e.g.

```
cores => join($solr_values, ','),
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about the effect of wrapping it with square brackets has